# Sort an array by object property value same as string in second array

Tags: javascript, arrays

Sorry about the title, I'm really not sure how to word this. I'm stuck, I need to sort an array by its object's title property value, into the same order of a second array of strings.

Basically, I have two arrays...

```
var titles = [
  'title1',
  'title2',
  'title3',
  'title4',
  'title5'
]

var objects = [
  {
    title: 'title5',
    ...//other values
  }, {
    title: 'title3',
    ...//other values
  }
  , {
    title: 'title4',
    ...//other values
  }, {
    title: 'title1',
    ...//other values
  }, {
    title: 'title2',
    ...//other values
  } 
]
```

I want to order the `objects` array in the same order as the strings in `titles` array. Is this possible? My code base has access to _underscore, or I can use plain ES6.

Comment: you want to `sort()` them on base of their **last number**?

Comment: no, whatever the order of the titles array is, those values could be anything as they are strings.

Comment: think of the titles array as a configuration for displaying the objects array. We use this currently to filter the objects array to contain only the match values, but i also now need to sort it in the same order.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create object from titles array and use it for ordering your array of objects.

```js
var objects = [{"title":"title5"},{"title":"title3"},{"title":"title4"},{"title":"title1"},{"title":"title2"}]
var titles = ['title1','title2','title3','title4','title5'].reduce((r, e, i) => Object.assign(r, {[e]: i}), {})

objects.sort((a, b) => titles[a.title] - titles[b.title])
console.log(objects)
```

Comment: This works only because you assume titles are in alphabetical order.

Comment: That's not true @UlysseBN -- it's sorting by the index in the array as it should. This is a good, efficient way to do this.

Comment: Oh I didn't see the index, maybe you should use more readable variables :)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's very possible. I personally would follow the 'decorate-sort-undecorate' pattern:

```
var titles = [
  'title1',
  'title2',
  'title3',
  'title4',
  'title5'
]

var objects = [
  {
    title: 'title5',
    //other values
  }, {
    title: 'title3',
    //other values
  }
  , {
    title: 'title4',
    //other values
  }, {
    title: 'title1',
    //other values
  }, {
    title: 'title2',
    //other values
  } 
]

var rankings = objects.map( o => ({
    object: o,
    ranking: titles.indexOf(o.title)
}))

rankings.sort((a, b) => a.ranking-b.ranking)

var sortedObjects = rankings.map(r => r.object);

console.log(sortedObjects);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [_.indexBy](https://underscorejs.org/#indexBy) to create an `Object` from `objects` variable and then map `titles`:

```
const objectsByTitle = _.indexBy(objects, 'title');
const result = titles.map(it => objectsByTitle[it]);
```

Titles should be unique ofc.

Answer (score -1):

There is a simple (but costful) solution:

```js
let titles = ['foo', 'bar', 'fizz', 'buzz']

let objects = [{title: 'fizz'}, {title: 'bar'}, {title: 'buzz'}, {title: 'foo'}]

console.log(titles.map(title => objects.find(o => o.title === title)))
```

However **this is a o(n²)** solution, I'm pretty sure your needs may be a little bit different and you could user an object, with `title` as keys.

Comment: I didn't downvote this — it works and might be good enough, but I suspect the downvote is because this is a quadratic time solution when a O(nlogn) solution exists.

Comment: @MarkMeyer I'd love to agree, but I wrote it in my answer already... I'll precise though, thanks for the comment.

Answer (score -1):

Can you check if this resolve what you are needing for?

```
var titles = [
  'title1',
  'title2',
  'title3',
  'title4',
  'title5'
]

var objects = [
  {
    title: 'title5',
  }, {
    title: 'title3',
  }
  , {
    title: 'title4',
  }, {
    title: 'title1',
  }, {
    title: 'title2',
  } 
]

function compare(a,b) {
  if (a.title < b.title)
    return -1;
  if (a.title > b.title)
    return 1;
  return 0;
}

console.log(objects.sort(compare));
```

https://jsfiddle.net/sxtn57gj/

Comment: The op doesn't want to sort by title, they want to sort by where the title apprears in `titles` array, which you are ignoring.