# Ordering array in defined order

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have tried several answers on SO but nothing seems to work. I am processing some data and placing it onto an array.  To do this I have the following

```
let aggData = [];

for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    let flag = data[i]['Category'].replace(/[_]/g, " ");
    flag = flag.toLowerCase()
        .split(' ')
        .map((s) => s.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + s.substring(1))
        .join(' ');

    aggData.push({
        "Flag": flag,
        "Freq": data[i]['Count']
    });
}
console.log( JSON.stringify( aggData ) );
```

The above outputs the following

```
[
    {"Flag":"Four","Freq":123},
    {"Flag":"One","Freq":234},
    {"Flag":"Three","Freq":345},
    {"Flag":"Two Days","Freq":456}
]
```

So it looks like it is naturally ordering it based on Alphabetical order.  I need it to be in an order I define, more specifically this

```
let order = ["Three", "One", "Two Days", "Four"];

let arr = aggData.sort(function(a,b) {
    return order.indexOf( a.key ) > order.indexOf( b.key );
});

console.log( 'Ordered: ', JSON.stringify( arr ) );
```

The above is returning the exact same order as before though.  How can I get it ordered the way I require?

Thanks

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54629515/sort-an-array-by-object-property-value-same-as-string-in-second-array/54629582#54629582

Comment: You have a typo. Use `a.Flag` and subtract inside the compare function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need to do is to use `sort` correctly, returning a number instead of a boolean... And of course using the right property...

```js
let data = [
    {"Flag":"Four","Freq":123},
    {"Flag":"One","Freq":234},
    {"Flag":"Three","Freq":345},
    {"Flag":"Two Days","Freq":456}
]


let order = ["Three", "One", "Two Days", "Four"];

let arr = data.sort(function(a,b) {
    return order.indexOf( a.Flag ) - order.indexOf( b.Flag );
});

console.log( 'Ordered: ', JSON.stringify( arr ) );
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to get the right property `Flag` and take the delta instead of a boolean value.

BTW, [`Array#sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) mutates the array.

```js
var aggData = [{ Flag: "Four", Freq: 123 }, { Flag: "One", Freq: 234 }, { Flag: "Three", Freq: 345 }, { Flag: "Two Days", Freq: 456 }],
    order = ["Three", "One", "Two Days", "Four"];

aggData.sort(function (a, b) {
    return order.indexOf(a.Flag) - order.indexOf(b.Flag);
});

console.log(aggData);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```